# How can I access a member of a class from a function via pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I wish to

1. create an array of class/struct items (`c1`)
2. then create an array of pointer to the original array (`*cp1`), which can be sorted
3. then access members of the class from within a function.

However I'm getting stuck at the initial function call.

Here's my basic code:

```
struct Car
{
    int speed;
};

Car c1[5];
Car *cp1[5];

int main() {
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        c1[i].speed = i;
        cp1[i] = &c1[i];
    }

    garage(cp1, 5);
}

void garage(Car **ar, int n) {
    int p = (*ar[n / 2])->speed;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are getting? Any specific error message, etc?

Comment: Add the error message **to your question**, not in the comments.

Comment: You can only call functions, which have been declared before.

Comment: This is actually a C question. Anyway, in `garage`, you're dereferencing the two-level pointer `ar` thrice: first the asterisk, then `[]`, then `->`.

Comment: @szczurcio no `typedef struct Car{ /* ... */} Car`, so looks like C++ to me.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Well, I meant to say that it doesn't use any C++ specific features (apart from what you pointed out, and that's not a major thing), so it could've been asked as a C question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funcion garage must be declared before you can refer it.

```
void garage(Car **ar, int n);

int main()
{
    //...
} 

void garage(Car **ar, int n) {
  //...
}
```

Function main in C++ shall have return type `int`

```
int main()
{
    //...
}
```

And within the function the correct expression will look

```
void garage(Car **ar, int n) {
  int p = (*ar )[n / 2]).speed;
}
```

Or

```
void garage(Car **ar, int n) {
  int p = ar[n / 2]->speed;
}
```

Or

```
void garage(Car **ar, int n) {
  int p = ( *ar[n / 2] ).speed;
}
```

Comment: I've marked this as correct, as although all the answers pointed out that my actual error was forgetting to prototype the function, Vlad was correct, my function expression was correct, and he has given alternate forms which also work

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `garage` function is not known to the compiler at the place where you call it, since it is defined below `main`. To fix it, either place the function definition above main, or introduce it with a prototype.

Second, at the line `int p = (*ar[n / 2])->speed;`, `*ar[n/2]` is not a pointer, so you should use `.` instead of `->`, as in `int p = (*ar[n / 2]).speed;`

Comment: My actual error was forgetting to prototype the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Car
{
    int speed;
};

Car c1[5];
Car *cp1[5];

void garage(Car **ar, int n); // forward declare garage

int main()
{
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
      c1[i].speed = i;
      cp1[i] = &c1[i];
    }

    garage(cp1, 5);
}


void garage(Car **ar, int n) {
    int p = ar[n / 2]->speed; // -> dereferences the pointer, you don't need to
}
```